# Output forEach loop to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Dumb question, getting acclimated to working with ES6 / Vanilla JS.

This is the loop working perfectly with console.log here....

```js
const theServices = 
      ["Accounting", "Big Data", "Business", "Category", "Concept", "Consultant", "Consumer", "Corporate", "Cost", "Customer", "Development", "Digital", "Distribution", "Due Diligence", "Financial", "Global Sourcing", "Go-to-market", "Growth", "Improvement", "Information", "Technology", "Innovation", "Lean", "Management", "Manufacturing", "Marketing", "Merchandising", "Mergers & Acquisitions", "Operations", "Organization / Organizational", "Performance", "Portfolio", "Post-merger", "Pricing", "Procurement", "Product", "Profitability", "Purchasing", "Restructuring", "Retail", "Revenue", "Sales", "Strategy", "Supply Chain", "Sustainable", "Technology", "Transformation", "Turnaround", "Zero-based", "Budgeting"];


theServices.forEach(function(element) {
    let formName = element;
    formName = formName.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '_').toLowerCase();

console.log( `
<div><input type="checkbox" id="${formName}" name="cpg_services" value="${formName}" />
<label for="${formName}">${element}
</label>
</div>
`)
});
```

```html
<div id="place-here"></div>
```

Now trying to insert into DOM with innerHTML returns undefined. What is the appropriate way to output loops like these?

```js
const theServices = 
      ["Accounting", "Big Data", "Business", "Category", "Concept", "Consultant", "Consumer", "Corporate", "Cost", "Customer", "Development", "Digital", "Distribution", "Due Diligence", "Financial", "Global Sourcing", "Go-to-market", "Growth", "Improvement", "Information", "Technology", "Innovation", "Lean", "Management", "Manufacturing", "Marketing", "Merchandising", "Mergers & Acquisitions", "Operations", "Organization / Organizational", "Performance", "Portfolio", "Post-merger", "Pricing", "Procurement", "Product", "Profitability", "Purchasing", "Restructuring", "Retail", "Revenue", "Sales", "Strategy", "Supply Chain", "Sustainable", "Technology", "Transformation", "Turnaround", "Zero-based", "Budgeting"];


let theseCheckBoxes =
    theServices.forEach(function(element) {
        let formName = element;
        formName = formName.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '_').toLowerCase();

        return `
<div><input type="checkbox" id="${formName}" name="cpg_services" value="${formName}" />
<label for="${formName}">${element}
</label>
</div>
`
    });
;

document.querySelector('#place_here').innerHTML = theseCheckBoxes;
```

```html
<div id="place_here"></div>
```

Comment: use `document.getElementById('place_here').innerHTML = 'your string'`

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't have a return value and doesn't use the return value of the callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ForEach` doesn't return anything. So `theseCheckBoxes` will be undefined. Try changing it to `map()` and the `join()` the results.

```js
const theServices = 
      ["Accounting", "Big Data", "Business", "Category", "Concept", "Consultant", "Consumer", "Corporate", "Cost", "Customer", "Development", "Digital", "Distribution", "Due Diligence", "Financial", "Global Sourcing", "Go-to-market", "Growth", "Improvement", "Information", "Technology", "Innovation", "Lean", "Management", "Manufacturing", "Marketing", "Merchandising", "Mergers & Acquisitions", "Operations", "Organization / Organizational", "Performance", "Portfolio", "Post-merger", "Pricing", "Procurement", "Product", "Profitability", "Purchasing", "Restructuring", "Retail", "Revenue", "Sales", "Strategy", "Supply Chain", "Sustainable", "Technology", "Transformation", "Turnaround", "Zero-based", "Budgeting"];


let theseCheckBoxes =
    theServices.map(function(element) {   // <-- map instead of forEach
        let formName = element;
        formName = formName.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '_').toLowerCase();

        return `
<div><input type="checkbox" id="${formName}" name="cpg_services" value="${formName}" />
<label for="${formName}">${element}
</label>
</div>
`
    });
;

document.querySelector('#place_here').innerHTML = theseCheckBoxes.join('\n');
```

```html
<div id="place_here"></div>
```

Comment: forEach `returns undefined`

Answer (score 3):

You can't [return a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) from the `forEach`, but you could just build up the html string while iterating or instead use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const theServices = 
      ["Accounting", "Big Data", "Business", "Category", "Concept", "Consultant", "Consumer", "Corporate", "Cost", "Customer", "Development", "Digital", "Distribution", "Due Diligence", "Financial", "Global Sourcing", "Go-to-market", "Growth", "Improvement", "Information", "Technology", "Innovation", "Lean", "Management", "Manufacturing", "Marketing", "Merchandising", "Mergers & Acquisitions", "Operations", "Organization / Organizational", "Performance", "Portfolio", "Post-merger", "Pricing", "Procurement", "Product", "Profitability", "Purchasing", "Restructuring", "Retail", "Revenue", "Sales", "Strategy", "Supply Chain", "Sustainable", "Technology", "Transformation", "Turnaround", "Zero-based", "Budgeting"];


let theseCheckBoxes = "";
    theServices.forEach(function(element) {
        let formName = element;
        formName = formName.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '_').toLowerCase();

        theseCheckBoxes +=`
<div><input type="checkbox" id="${formName}" name="cpg_services" value="${formName}" />
<label for="${formName}">${element}
</label>
</div>
`
    });
;

document.querySelector('#place_here').innerHTML = theseCheckBoxes;
```

```html
<div id="place_here"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to add another solution, and that would be to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to reduce the array down to a string like this:

```js
const theServices = ["Accounting", "Big Data", "Business", "Category", "Concept", "Consultant", "Consumer", "Corporate", "Cost", "Customer", "Development", "Digital", "Distribution", "Due Diligence", "Financial", "Global Sourcing", "Go-to-market", "Growth", "Improvement", "Information", "Technology", "Innovation", "Lean", "Management", "Manufacturing", "Marketing", "Merchandising", "Mergers & Acquisitions", "Operations", "Organization / Organizational", "Performance", "Portfolio", "Post-merger", "Pricing", "Procurement", "Product", "Profitability", "Purchasing", "Restructuring", "Retail", "Revenue", "Sales", "Strategy", "Supply Chain", "Sustainable", "Technology", "Transformation", "Turnaround", "Zero-based", "Budgeting"];

let str = theServices.reduce(function(str, element) {
  let formName = element;
  formName = formName.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '_').toLowerCase();

  return str.concat(`<div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="${formName}" name="cpg_services" value="${formName}" />
            <label for="${formName}">${element}</label>
          </div>`)
}, '');

document.querySelector('#place_here').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="place_here"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning (since [forEach returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) `undefined`), append the html to a string `let str = ''` and place the string in the div. like this:

```js
const theServices = ["Accounting", "Big Data", "Business", "Category", "Concept", "Consultant", "Consumer", "Corporate", "Cost", "Customer", "Development", "Digital", "Distribution", "Due Diligence", "Financial", "Global Sourcing", "Go-to-market", "Growth", "Improvement", "Information", "Technology", "Innovation", "Lean", "Management", "Manufacturing", "Marketing", "Merchandising", "Mergers & Acquisitions", "Operations", "Organization / Organizational", "Performance", "Portfolio", "Post-merger", "Pricing", "Procurement", "Product", "Profitability", "Purchasing", "Restructuring", "Retail", "Revenue", "Sales", "Strategy", "Supply Chain", "Sustainable", "Technology", "Transformation", "Turnaround", "Zero-based", "Budgeting"];

let str = ''

theServices.forEach(function(element) {
  let formName = element;
  formName = formName.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '_').toLowerCase();

  str += `<div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="${formName}" name="cpg_services" value="${formName}" />
            <label for="${formName}">${element}</label>
          </div>`
});

document.querySelector('#place_here').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="place_here"></div>
```

Comment: I should have used map, but this is a smart solution for turning forEach into a string. Thanks!